# Using char and char[] in C++

Tags: c++, char

I'm having trouble using type `char`. When I initialize my `ID` and `Name` in my struct by a constructor, why am I getting this error message? `"expression must be a modifiable lvalue"`.

```
struct Staff
{
    char ID[8];
    char Name[30];
    Staff()
    {
        ID = "";
        Name = "";
    }
};
```

Comment: You are mixing C & C++

Comment: And poorly at that, as the code above won't work in C either, even without the c++ class stuff.

Comment: You can't assign a string literal to an array, you need to copy characters in.

Comment: Why do you put C in the question title, and then tag it C++? How are we supposed to answer the question when we don't even know what language it is? Given that you show C++ code (it has a constructor, which is only valid in C++), can we ignore the "C" part?

Comment: @jalf yeah i get it, that's my fault, sorry for this.
I know I mixed 2 in my code, cause I was taught C, but C++ is more convenient. So I try to mixed them.

Comment: @GHD, C does not have constructors. Are you sure you mean C and not C++?

Comment: Is it C or C++? What compiler are you using? You have a constructor but C doesn't have constructors

Comment: @GHD well, you're free to use whichever language you like. We just need to know which language we should assume when answering your question. :)

Comment: THIS QUESTION IS NOT C AS IT IS WRITTEN, IS IT C or C++? PLEASE MAKE UP YOUR MIND.

Comment: @GIJoe. Please don't shout. This isn't a crowded bus station, it's a tiny comment thread.

Answer (score 6):

<sup>*Since this question is tagged C++ and the code make uses of C++ only features (such as constructors), I'm going assume you have mistakenly confused C with C++ in your title.*</sup>

Don't use `char` arrays when you really mean strings. Use `std::string` instead:

```
struct Staff {
    std::string ID;
    std::string Name;
};
```

In this way the default constructor will behave as expected and you won't even need to specify it. The only additional line you'll need is the one that includes the necessary header:

```
#include <string>
```

on the very top of the file.

Comment: It's C, so your answer is now obsolete. OP edited.

Comment: @GIJoe, actually it's still not C (C does not have constructors).

Comment: Of course, I am just going off what it is tagged.

Comment: @GIJoe, I have the strange feeling that OP is extremely confused about C and C++. :)

Comment: Yep :) ". I know I mixed 2 in my code, cause I was taught C, but C++ is more convenient. So I try to mixed them"

Comment: @GIJoe, There. Apparently my answer is relevant again.

Comment: Oh for crying out loud, the OP can't make up their mind. I give up. Abandon ship

Answer (score 4):

`char` in C and C++ is just another numeric type, like `int`, but smaller (generally one byte). An array of chars is not special -- it's basically a raw hunk of memory. A string literal is internally an array of chars as well, but C++ has no built-in support for copying arrays with `operator=` -- you have to copy the bytes yourself, for example via the (deprecated) `strcpy` C function (include `cstring`).

In C++, the usual way to deal with strings is to use `std::string` (include `string`), which is a class that wraps the string's bytes for you, and implements string copying, comparison, etc. in a clean, intuitive fashion.

You're also missing a semicolon at the end of the `Staff` structure, which will cause some interesting compile errors :-)

Answer (score 2):

You cannot change the value of `ID` or `Name` since it is an array, not a pointer.

Either declare it as char pointer (in this case it's better to declare it as `const char*`):

```
const char *ID;
const char *Name;
```

Or use `memset`:

```
memset(ID, '\0', sizeof(ID));
memset(Name, '\0', sizeof(Name));
```

This will "initialize" your `char` arrays.

You can do the same to assign a string to the array using `strncpy`

```
strncpy(Name, "John Doe", sizeof(Name)-1);
```

The -1 accounts for the null terminating character.

Comment: thank you, I will try this as you helped.

Answer (score 1):

What you need to do is

```
struct Staff
{
    char ID[8];
    char Name[30];

    Staff() :
        ID{0},  // Null terminate the array same as, ID[0] = 0;
        Name{0} // Null terminate the array same as, Name[0] = 0;
    {
    }
};
```

Comment: but without the constructor, because this is supposedly C code

Comment: @jalf Thanks for pointing that out. I had assumed it was C++.

Comment: why we have to declare ID{0}, Name{0}?
what is that stand for. thank you.

Comment: In C++ this will initialize all values of the array with the value 0.

Comment: so we dont have to initialize them anymore by using this?

Comment: It might be helpful to put some of these explanatory comments in the posted answer, as well :)

Comment: @jalf: It's C++ now :( OP retagged